# C++: Error retrieving STL map from another map

Tags: c++11, stl

I have the following piece of code -

```
#include <map>

using Type1 = std::map<std::string, unsigned long long>;
using Type2 = std::map<std::string, Type1>;

class T
{
   private:
      Type2 mymap;

   public:
      const Type1& get(const std::string& key) const;
};

const Type1& T::get(const std::string& key) const
{
   return mymap[key];
}

int main(void)
{
}
```

This does not compile and the compiler complains -

> ```
> maps.cpp: In member function ‘const Type1& T::get(const string&)
> const’: maps.cpp:17:20: error: passing ‘const Type2 {aka const
> std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>,
> long long unsigned int> >}’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp,
> _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::map<std::basic_string<char>, long
> long unsigned int>; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >;
> _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, long long unsigned int> > >;
> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type =
> std::map<std::basic_string<char>, long long unsigned int>;
> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type =
> std::basic_string<char>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
> return mymap[key];
>                 ^
> ```

I need help understanding this error. From what I can tell I am not modifying "this" in the get function.

Thanks!

Comment: `map`'s `operator[]` may modify the map (to insert a blank entry if the key does not exist), so you can't use it in a `const` member function

Comment: You could either make the function non-const, or use `map::find` instead (throwing an exception if the entry doesn't already exist in the map)

Comment: @M.M Thanks! I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors comes from the fact that
[`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)  *can*
inserts the *key* if the it **does not** exist.

You could do a `std::map::find` first as a check.

Comment: I always suggest using `count` instead of `find` because I find it shorter to understand. Anyway, one could also use `at` in place of `operator[]` which throws an exception if the key doesn't exist.